# ¿Cómo hallar el nivel de un nodo en un ABB?

Tags: java, estructuras-de-datos, árboles-binarios, nodos, busqueda

Estoy tratando de hacer un metodo que me retorne el nivel de un elemento dado por parámetro, en un arbol binario de busqueda.

Mi arbol es el siguiente:

```
               8
        3            10

    1      6      9      14   // el nodo padre 14 tiene un nodo izq hijo 13

        4     7       13     // los nodos 4 y 7 son nodos hijos del nodo 6
```

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
// METODO BUSCAR NIVEL DE UN NODO
int cont = 0;
public int nivel(Arbin<Integer> raiz, int elem){
    if(raiz != null){
        if(raiz.obtener() == elem){
            cont++; 
        }else{
            if(raiz.izq() != null){
                cont++;
                nivel(raiz.izq(),elem);
            }else if(raiz.der() != null){
                cont++;
                nivel(raiz.der(), elem);
            } 
        }   
    }
    return cont;
}
```

Al hacer el llamado al metodo pidiendo el nivel del nodo/elemento 6: recibo el sgte output

```
El nivel del nodo dado es: 2   // cuando en realidad está en el nivel 3 (teniendo la raiz como nivel 
                               //   1 )
```

Debugeando un poco el código me doy cuenta que en un punto durante la ejecución de las llamadas recursivas, llega al elemento 1 y al no tener enlace izquierdo ni derecho, se sale de los condicionales y me retorna el ultimo valor guardado que viene siendo 2. Estoy un poco estancado ahí, en cómo evito que no me recorra todo el arbol como deberia ser hasta encontrar el nodo dado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public int nivel(Arbin<Integer> raiz, int elem){
    if (raiz == null) 
        return -1; // no encontrado

    r = raiz.obtener();

    if (r == elem) return 0;

    int res = 0;
    if (r < elem) res = nivel(raiz.izq(),elem);    
    if (r > elem) res = nivel(raiz.der(),elem);

    if (res < 0) return res;

    return 1+res;

}
```

Una version ligeramente más eficiente (especialmente en lenguajes que manejan recursion de cola):

```
public int nivel(Arbin<Integer> raiz, int elem){
    return implNivel(raiz, elem, 0);
}

private int implNivel(Arbin<Integer> raiz, int elem, int res){
    if (raiz == null) 
        return -1; // no encontrado

    r = raiz.obtener();

    if (r == elem) return res;

    if (r < elem) return nivel(raiz.izq(),elem,1+res);    

    if (r > elem) return nivel(raiz.der(),elem,1+res);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Estuve intentandolo desde que publiqué la pregunta y ya hallé la solución.

Lo que pasa es que no estaba teniendo en cuenta la estructura de un arbol binario de busqueda, el cual sus elementos estan ordenados teniendo los datos menores que la raiz en la izquierda y los datos mayores que la raíz a la derecha.

Teniendo en cuenta lo anterior, hacían falta los condicionales que gestionarán esas validaciones, por ende, el código se vería algo así:

```
// METODO PARA BUSCAR NIVEL DE UN NODO
public int nivel(int elem){
    if(r == null)
        return -1;         // va a retornar -1 cuando el arbol esté vacío
    else
        return nivel(r, elem);
}

int cont = 0;
public int nivel(Arbin<Integer> raiz, int elem){
    if(elem == raiz.obtener()){
        cont++;
    }else{
        if(elem < raiz.obtener()){      // pregunta si es menor que la raiz
            if(raiz.izq() != null){     // para realizar la busqueda por el lado
                cont++;                 // izq del arbol y aumentar el cont
                nivel(raiz.izq(),elem);
            }else{
                return cont=-1;      // en caso de no encontrarlo retorna -1
            }   
        }else{                       // cuando el elemento sea mayor que la raiz
            if(raiz.der() != null){  // hace el mismo procedimiento pero por el 
                cont++;              // lado der del arbol y aumenta el cont
                nivel(raiz.der(),elem);
            }else{
                return cont=-1;     // si no lo encuentra retorna -1
            }
        }        
    }
    if(cont == -1)        // si cont == -1, va a retornar ese mismo -1
        return cont;
    else
        return cont-1;    // sino, va a retornar el cont - 1 con el fin de
}                         // que el nivel se maneje desde 0 comenzando en la raiz
```